# calling Python kwargs functions with special keys

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I want to use kwargs in Python like this:

```
def myfunc(**kwargs):
  ... do something ...


x = myfunc(a=1, b=2, #value=4)
```

But I can't, because `#value` is not a valid Python keyword

Alternatively, I can do this:

```
x = myfunc(**{'a':1, 'b':2, '#value': 4})
```

which is kind of awkward.

Is there any way I can use some kind of hybrid approach here?

```
# this doesn't work
x = myfunc(a=1,b=2, {'#value': 4})
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can:

```
x = myfunc(a=1, b=2, **{'#value': 4})
```

Using explicit keyword parameters does not prevent you from passing in a dictionary *as well*.

Demo:

```
>>> def myfunc(**kwargs):
...     print kwargs
... 
>>> myfunc(a=1, b=2, **{'#value': 4})
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, '#value': 4}
```

Comment: whee! I thought there might be something! Hurray for Python!